# Doubt in integral substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am not able to figure out what substitution to use in the following integral
$$
\int \frac{(x-1)e^x}{(x+1)^3}dx
$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes exactly sir

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can use integration by parts with $$u'=\frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)^3}=\frac{(x+1-2)}{(x+1)^3}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}$$ $$v=e^x$$ from which $$u=-\frac{x}{(x+1)^2}$$ $$v'=e^x$$ and a second integration by parts will lead you to the result.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: @Fantini. Thank you. I appreciate. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How about let $u = x + 1 $ first. And express the integral in $u$.

Comment: Yes, but how does that help remove the exponential part?

Comment: You should not try to remove the exponential part; if you do it, you will introduce a nighmare for the remaining part.

Comment: Then how would you transform this integral